# Split pandas column into multiple rows, where splitting is on the value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a pandas df that looks like this:

```
id        text
10000     Hi, how are you? [10000] Good thanks, yourself? [10000] I'm great.
20000     Is it hot there today? [20000] No, it's raining. [2000] Oh, too bad!
30000     What's your name [3000] Steve, and yours? [3000] Rita.
```

Here's the df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1000, "Hi, how are you? [10000] Good thanks, yourself? [10000] I'm great."],
    [2000, "Is it hot there today? [20000] No, it's raining. [2000] Oh, too bad!"],
    [3000, "What's your name [3000] Steve, and yours? [3000] Rita."]], columns=['id', 'text'])
```

I want to add a new column that splits the 'text' column into a list, based on the value in the 'id' column.

```
id        text                                               lines

10000     "Hi, how are you? [10000] Good thanks, yourself?   ["Hi, how are you?", 
          [10000] I'm great."                                 "Good thanks, ...",
                                                              "I'm great."]
20000     Is it hot there today? [20000] No, it's raining.  ["Is it hot there ...",
          [2000] Oh, too bad!                                "No, it's raining.",
                                                             "Oh, too bad!"]
30000     What's your name? [3000] Steve, and yours?        ["What's your name?",
          [3000] Rita.                                        "Steve, and yours?",
                                                              "Rita."]
```

I tried this:

```
df ['lines'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['text'].split(x['id']))
```

But I get a KeyError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc 
(pandas/index.c:4279)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:8543)()

TypeError: an integer is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-14-e50f764c5674> in <module>()
----> 1 df ['lines'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['text'].split(x['id']))


KeyError: ('text', 'occurred at index id')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `axis=1` and proper separator.

```
In [548]: df.apply(lambda x: x['text'].split(' [%s] ' % x['id']), axis=1)
Out[548]:
0    [Hi, how are you?, Good thanks, yourself?, I'm...
1    [Is it hot there today?, No, it's raining., Oh...
2         [What's your name, Steve, and yours?, Rita.]
dtype: object
```